# What is the best method for storing (encoding/decoding) HTML in a MSSQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, html, sql-server

Currently I'm running with a textarea in a form set to POST:

```
<textarea name="post_content">HTML CODE PASTED HERE AND THEN SUBMITTED</textarea>
```

On submit, the PHP kicks in:

```
<?php 

    //Encode the HTML for storage (is this the best method?)
    $page_content = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'page_content', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

    //SQL to insert into a table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO advanced_cms_pages (page_content) VALUES(?)";
    $params = array(
        array(&$page_content, NULL, NULL, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_TEXT)
        );        
    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $connection, $sql, $params );

    //Check if the sql was successful
    if (!sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {  
        die (slqsrv_errors());
    }

?>
```

Then on output to the browser:

```
<?php

    //Decode on output
    echo htmlspecialchars_decode($page['page_content']);

?>
```

It appears that this is not a full solution though as sometimes I still get characters that aren't encoded/decoded properly. Any suggestions?  Is there a proven method for HTML storage in a mssql database?

### Examples:

- Newline is an issue "\n" comes out as it's html code equivalent `&#10;`
- Carriage returns also, "\r" comes out as `&#13;`
- Possible others that I haven't see yet.

### Server build:

- PHP 5.4.14
- MSSQL 2008 R2
- IIS7.5

Comment: Could you post examples of characters that _aren't_ encoded/decoded properly?

Comment: Examples added, I've only been able to track down two as of right now, newlines and carriage returns.  Though, I'm worried that if these didn't get properly converted, there will be others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use htmlentities function for encode and html_entity_decode for decode.

It's the better way for me. I work with UTF8 character set.